# Youtube api expires_in fix limit?

Tags: youtube-api

token received by the time of 1 hour with YouTube 's happening How can I extend it ?

> PHP Youtube Api V3

```
"access_token" : "abc123",
"token_type" : "abc123",
"expires_in" : 0000, <<<<<<<<<<< TİME
"refresh_token" : "abc123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a refresh token to get a new access token. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) for more information. There's detailed guides on getting a refresh token for server-side web apps, client-side web apps, and installed apps.